# Creating a Random Number Calculator

Tags: java, calculator, joptionpane

Please help. I'm trying to create a Math learning system where there is a menu of 4 different mathematical operations. When an operation was selected, it will generate a set of number performing that operation. Please help me to fix the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class advanceMath {
public static void main(String[]args) {


    Random firstnum = new Random();
    int number1 = firstnum.nextInt(9)+1;

    Random secondnum = new Random();
    int number2 = secondnum.nextInt(9);


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String dec;

    int firstnum,secondnum; int total = 0 ;

    System.out.println("choose letter ");
    System.out.println("A.Addition");
    System.out.println("B.SUBTRACTION");
    System.out.println("C.MULTIPLICATION");
    System.out.println("D.DIVISION");

    System.out.println("letter i choose"); 
        dec = input.next();

    if(dec.equalsIgnoreCase("a")){

        System.out.println(number1);
        firstnum = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println(number2);
        secondnum = input.nextInt();

    total = number1 + number2;

        System.out.println("Total = "+ total);
        System.out.println("Congratulation"); }


    if(dec.equalsIgnoreCase("b")){
        System.out.println(number1);
        firstnum = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println(number2);
        secondnum = input.nextInt();

    total = number1 - number2;

    System.out.println("Total = "+ total);
    System.out.println("Congratulation"); }

    if(dec.equalsIgnoreCase("c")){
        System.out.println(number1);
        firstnum = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println(number2);
        secondnum = input.nextInt();

    total = number1 * secondnum;

    System.out.println("Total = "+ total);
    System.out.println("Congratulation"); }

    if(dec.equalsIgnoreCase("d")){
        System.out.println(number1);
        firstnum = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println(number2);
        secondnum = input.nextInt();

    total = firstnum / secondnum;

        System.out.println("Total = "+ total);
        System.out.println("Congratulation"); }

        else System.exit(0);
}
```

}

Comment: where is JOptionPane here?

Comment: Ok, and what's the question? Please don't tell us "how do I build that UI" or similar. If you have questions on that search the net for tutorials and come back with specific questions. If you already have specific questions then ask those and show what you've tried.

Comment: I'm just asking your help to fix the error sir

Comment: Whats the error ? please add that too in your question

Comment: whenever I run the program there is an error in the second line after the Scanner input saying that firstnum and secondnum variables are already declared defined in the main method or the assigned value is never used, Please help me to fix the problem.

Comment: "_firstnum and secondnum variables are already declared defined in the main method_" Which part of that message is confusing? It says you used the same name 2 times for a variable. Sure enough, about 5 lines of code apart there it is... `Random firstnum = new Random();` - `int firstnum,secondnum;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring `firstnum` and `secondnum` two times

```
Random firstnum = new Random();

Random secondnum = new Random();
```

And

```
int firstnum,secondnum; int total = 0 ;
```

Remove / rename one of these.

Answer (score 1):

You give the same name `Random firstnum` and `int firstnum`
same as `secondnum`. Change the name of any one